# mock a function within same service for unittesting

Tags: angular

I have this class service in Angular 6:

```
   export class AppService {

     setValues(): Observable<any> {

       const vm: any = this;
       return new Observable(observer => {
       vm.currentValues().subscribe(data => {
           // continue modifying data and reset it

        });
     });
   }

   public currentValues(): Observable<any> {


   return new Observable(observer => {
     observer.next('data goes here')

    });

  } 
 }
```

The currentValues() is quite random so cant relay on it. How can I mock it in my unittest file and use it when testing setValues() method?

I have tried the following but I cant see how I can put it into use?

```
export function mockCurrentValues () : Observable<any> {

    return of(
      'data'
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the complete code? Regardless tho, I think you should try returnValue instead like this:

```
    const injector = getTestBed();
    appService = injector.get( AppService );

    // spy the internal method setValues() calls now and return observable

    spyOn( appService, 'currentValues' ).and.returnValue(of(data));

    appService.setValues().subscribe(data=>{
        // do your test here
        done()
    }

    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `AppService` is an `@Injectable()` and you are writing unit tests for the provider. you can use `spys` provided by `Jasmine Framework`

https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

```
import { getTestBed, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppService } from 'path/to/app/service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

describe( 'App Service', function() {
    let appService : AppService;

    beforeEach( function() {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
            providers: [ AppService ],
        } );
        const injector = getTestBed();
        appService = injector.get( AppService );

        spyOn( appService, 'currentValues' ).and.callFake( () => {
            return of( 'data' );
        } );
    } );

    describe( 'setValues', function() {

        it( 'should set correct values', function() {
            appService.setValues().subscribe();
            // setValues will receive 'data' from the spy we just created while calling currentValues() method
            // write your unit tests here
        } );

    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks @yashpatelyk: I am getting the error "vm.currentValues() is not a function"

Comment: Try using 'this', instead of vm. We are using arrow functions so we can use 'this'

Comment: Okay, can you share you entire code? I will see what's the issue. Because this exact   code is working for me.

Comment: @yashpateylk: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjgkj1 it uses pouchdb but I believe the idea of mocking is so i don't really care where currentValues() gets its data.